# Annotate a datetime field from another date time and duration in minutes

Tags: django, django-annotate

I want to annotate a datetime field to a queryset using timedelta and F objects

Example:

```
Model.objects.annotate(end_time=F('start_time')+timedelta(minutes=F('meeting_duration')))
```

Here I have a field "start_time" and "meeting_duration" in my table and I want to calculate and annotate an end_time using datetime.timedelta

And thereafter filter the queryset using the annotated field.

```
queryset.filter(end_time__gte=self.end_time)
```

Now I get this error:

> TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: F

Comment: A `timedelta` does not understand an `F` expression, only `int`s, and other integral-like types.

Comment: understood. So whats a solution? As in how can i get the expected result? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Why not make `meeting_duration` a `DurationField`?

Comment: editing table fields is not possible atm as its deployed in production, any other options?@WillemVanOnsem